# Pyinstaller compile error on unused library

Tags: python, pyinstaller

`AssertionError: Failed to determine matplotlib's data directory!`

Im not using maptolib anywhere and there is another error assiciated with it

```
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 51, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

My command

```py
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile -w --console --name "Project1" --add-data "C:/Users/user/Desktop/bot/app.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/user/Desktop/bot/czgen.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/user/Desktop/bot/sk.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/user/Desktop/bot/site.py;." --hidden-import "colorama"  "C:/Users/user/Desktop/bot/main.py"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use a clean virtual enviornement to compile your app with only the modules and libraries necessary to run your app installed + pyinstaller

Comment: @Alexander What do you mean by that? How do I do this I hate tried doing it in VSCode and the folder CMD but same error

Answer (score 1):

i think one of the modules you used needs matplotlib, so check if everything works. otherwise, i would suggest to clear out the virtual enviroment and downloading everything back. this way the issue will be inside of the code and not in pyinstaller, therefore it'll be easier to debug and find the issue.